# Async call to HttpClient get

Tags: angular, httpclient

The following code is used to get a file asynchronously. 
This method belongs to a service.
It is called from the constructor of AppComponent class.

```js
public async ReadConfiguration () 
  {
      await this.http.get ('http://localhost:80/api/Target.xml',{ responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(
      (val) => {
          console.log("GET call successful value returned in body", val);
                      
      },
      response => {
          console.log("GET call in error", response);
      },
      () => {
          console.log("The GET observable is now completed.");
      }); 

    /*await this.http.get('http://localhost:80/api/Target.xml',{ responseType: 'text' }).toPromise()
    .then((data: any) => {
     
      console.time('request-length');
      console.log(data);
      console.timeEnd('request-length');

    });*/
  }
```

Right after calling "ReadConfiguration" I called to:

```
console.log ('Completed');
```

But according to the console, the HttpClient.get is completed after 'Completed'. 
Can you please tell what is wrong in my code ?

Thank you in advance,
Zvika

Comment: There's not too much sensible in your code. 
`await` makes no sense if you subscribe. `subscribe()` does not return a promise, so `await` will do nothing. You are totally confusing async code, a good advice would be to step a few steps back and start with the basics. Learn about why we `return` in a function, do some training on promises without `async/await`, ...

Comment: I’m surpised it’s even possible to await a Subscription..? Why are you using async await here if you have access to an Observable?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a promise for the `await`. The `get` of the `HttpClient` is returning Observable, while `await` is expecting a `promise`.

You can use `toPromise()` function to convert an Observable to a Promise.

You can also use the `Pipes` like `tap`, `catchError` and `finalize` to not subscribing the Observable inside the service.

```
return this.http.get ('http://localhost:80/api/Target.xml',{ responseType: 'text' })
  .pipe(
    tap(val => console.log("GET call successful value returned in body", val)),
    catchError(error => console.log("GET call in error", error)),
    finalize(() => console.log("The GET observable is now completed."))
  )
);
```

For the commented part, even though you are using the `toPromise()`, it still won't work as if you put the logging right after the calling.

async functions returns a promise which you should wait for then log the value. You either use the `then` like `ReadConfiguration().then(() => console.log("Completed"))` or use another `async/await`.

Comment: Hi yazantahhan, all,

Comment: The code is the question contains also a commented code with toPromise. It does not work either. Can you please tell why ?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) should be used to wait for a `Promise`. But when you call `.subscribe()`, it returns a `Subscription` object.

> If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a
>   Promise, it's converted to a resolved Promise.

This means that you don't actually wait until you GET request is completed, that's why you see  'Completed' and then 'The GET observable is now completed.'